# Why router event not showing routes in component and showing error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Below is my component's code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  showMenu:any='';
  constructor(router:Router) {
    router.events.forEach((event) => {
      if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
          this.showMenu = event.url !== "/newsection";
          console.log(event.url);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> ReferenceError: NavigationStart is not defined

Comment: What does this question have to do with php and react?

Comment: Also, post code, not images of code

Comment: Also, the reason for the error is because `NavigationStart` is actually not defined. You need to import it.

Comment: how to define Navigationstart  @AyushGupta

Comment: Add it to the import of `@angular/router`.

Comment: already imported

Comment: No. Just read your code. It imports Component, Router, and ActivatedRoute. Not NavigationStart.

Comment: thaks for the help solved

Comment: Both below answer is  correct for me thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router, ActivatedRoute,NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      showMenu:any='';
      constructor(router:Router) {
        router.events.forEach((event) => {
          if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
              this.showMenu = event.url !== "/newsection";
              console.log(event.url);
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

by:

```
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
```

Then you can subscribe like that:

```
router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        // ...
    }
}
```